# Delete post file not working in php function

Tags: php

I have below code to delete posts from my website. This function is working for video posts and it delete video post perfectly. But it is not working for image posts and does not delete post image from web directory. My code is

```
function delete_post($id, $fromStory = false) {
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ($fromStory and !$post['is_story']) return true;
    if (!$fromStory and !can_edit_post($post)) return false;
    if ($post['images']) {
        $images = perfectUnserialize($post['images']);
        if($images) {
            foreach($images as $image) {
                delete_file(path($image));
            }
        }

        if ($post['video']) {
            delete_file(path($post['video']));
        }
}
```

Besides i have delete old stories function given below

```
function delete_old_stories() {
    $time = time() - (3600 * config('story-deleted-at', 24));
    $query = db()->query("SELECT id,post_id FROM story_posts WHERE time_created < $time ");
    while($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        db()->query("DELETE FROM story_posts WHERE id=?", $fetch['id']); //delete story posts
        delete_post($fetch['post_id'], true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is delete file function

```
function delete_file($path)
{
    $basePath = path();
    $basePath2 = $basePath . '/';

    if ($path == $basePath or $path == $basePath2) return false;
    if (is_dir($path) === true) {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (in_array($file->getBasename(), array('.', '..')) !== true) {
                if ($file->isDir() === true) {
                    rmdir($file->getPathName());
                } else if (($file->isFile() === true) || ($file->isLink() === true)) {
                    unlink($file->getPathname());
                }
            }
        }

        return rmdir($path);
    } else if ((is_file($path) === true) || (is_link($path) === true)) {
        return unlink($path);


    }

    return false;
}
```

For each story,
Image file in directory is

```
_1000_8f81946314be5cfe962480b96c7df11e.jpg
```

For Post,
Image files in directory are

```
_1000_8f81946314be5cfe962480b96c7df11e.jpg
_600_8f81946314be5cfe962480b96c7df11e.jpg
```

Delete Story working fine and deletes story images but  delete post does not delete images.

i have tried var_dump it is giving message as string(94)

```
"/home3/myaim/abc.com/files/uploads/posts/photo/_%w_79b3d75a626fc66d67eee4ec9289‌​bd0a.jpg" Post deleted successfully
```

but image file path which is to be deleted is string(94)

```
"/home3/myaim/abc.com/files/uploads/posts/photo/_1000_79b3d75a626fc66d67eee4ec92‌​89bd0a.jpg" Post deleted successfully
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Ensure `path($image)` gives right path

Comment: can you please do echo path($post['video']) for us, so we can see what it's doing on the backend. Then try it with $image and let us know. Then please do print_r($image) in the foreach, as well as show us the $post['images'] before the foreach. thx

Comment: please see my  updated question

Answer (score 1):

you can use [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) for Delete a filename.

example:

```
unlink('imageText.jpg');
```